# Is there a limit for zip() elements in loops in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, list-comprehension

Something weird happened to me today. I needed to create a list based on a sequence of if statements. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
prom_lect4b_rbd    prom_lect2m_rbd   prom_lect8b_rbd   prom_lect6b_rbd
     100                np.nan            80                200
     np.nan             np.nan            40                1000
     np.nan             np.nan           np.nan              90
     230                 100              80                100
```

Columns are orderer according to their priority. The list (or column) I'm trying to create takes the first value from those rows that is not `nan`. So, in this case I want a column that looks like this:

```
simce_final_lect
     100
     40
     90
     230
```

I tried the following:

```
cols=[simces.prom_lect4b_rbd, simces.prom_lect2m_rbd, simces.prom_lect8b_rbd, simces.prom_lect6b_rbd]

simce_final_lect=[j if np.isnan(j)==False else k if np.isnan(k)==False
                  else l if np.isnan(l)==False else m if np.isnan(m)==False 
                  else np.nan for j,k,l,m in zip(cols[0],cols[1],cols[2],cols[3])]
```

And that just copies two values (out of 8752) to the list. But if I limit my zip to just `j,k,l`, it works perfectly:

```
simce_final_lect=[j if np.isnan(j)==False else k if np.isnan(k)==False
                  else l if np.isnan(l)==False  
                  else np.nan for j,k,l in zip(cols[0],cols[1],cols[2])]
```

Do you know what is happening? Else, is there a more efficient solution to my problem?

Comment: Your last column is shorter than the others. `zip` stops when the shorter list ends. BTW: you should really consider extracting the expression that takes the value into a function: `first_not_nan = lambda vals: next(x for x in vals if not math.isnan(x))` then `result = list(map(first_not_nan, zip(A,B,C,D)))`.

Comment: Thanks Bakuriu! Could you explain me a little further your approach? I'm not really used to lambda expressions outside  the apply function when trying to do an operation in every row of a Series. When I used both commands it got me a list of just 148 values. Maybe it stopped when it found a row consisting of only `nan` ? How could I fill it with a nan in that case? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bfill(axis=1)` and select the first col.

```
df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]

0    100.0
1     40.0
2     90.0
3    230.0
Name: prom_lect4b_rbd, dtype: float64

## For list
df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0].tolist()
['100', '40', 90, '230']
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! Pythonic and simple, way less convoluted than my solution.

Comment: @JuanC Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `first_valid_index()`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
0    100.0
1     40.0
2     90.0
3    230.0
dtype: float64
```